# CSS - Sass : different render from codepen to vscode & sass

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

there is something i dont understand,
i've made a codepen for a burger menu design. And it do work without problem.

[CodePen](https://%20https://codepen.io/Woots/pen/bGaEmqm?editors=1100)

Now, when i copy paste the exact same code to vscode ( using sass ) the middle bar just do not display.
And only start display when i set the size ( line 13 ) to 3rem;

Anyone have any idea about why there it doesn't work ( i even tried to put the code into a classic html css without any other extension or so, and i still dont end with the codepen result )

thanks

Comment: Please try to edit the question to make it more clear, maybe a screenshot from VSCode. Do you have the same width and height, anything else that might be different except for the environment?

Comment: I copy pasted the exact same code from codepen to vscode and changed strictly nothing. I even tried the code with css only files ( meaning one html and one css without them beeing part of a project or so ) Even tried by removing the css reset i had.

Answer (score 0):

Alright solved my own issue;
it was because a default box-sizing: border-box setting,
while with a content-box it all work fine.
( certainly missed something because of some reset or so )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).